# Python: Matplotlib: how to print ONE text with different sizes in it?

Tags: python, text, matplotlib, fonts, size

is it possible in matplotlib to have a textbox with different font sizes within one string?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this can be done without using the LaTeX text renderer. To use this do,

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
```

Then you can print multi-fontsize strings using standard LaTeX syntax, e.g.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
ax = plt.axes()
ax.text(0.5, 0.5, r'{\tiny tiny text} normal text {\Huge HUGE TEXT}')
```

Sometimes the LaTeX font renderer isn't ideal (e.g. note that tick-label fonts are different than normal MPL tick labels), but it is certainly more flexible.

[image]